# Como retornar uma coluna específica como um elemento com cláusula FOR XML AUTO

Tags: sql-server, xml, for

Eu preciso fazer com que uma determinada coluna seja um elemento no xml de retorno quando eu utilizo a cláusula FOR XML AUTO. O retorno automático transforma todos os campos em atributos do elemento correspondente. Tudo bem, mas um ou outro campo eu preciso que seja um elemento.

Tenho duas tabelas:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table1](
    [Id] [int] NULL,
    [Nome] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Table2]    Script Date: 02/03/2018 16:24:11 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table2](
    [Id] [int] NULL,
    [DataVencimento] [date] NULL,
    [Table1_Id] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table1] ([Id], [Nome]) VALUES (1, N'AAA')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table1] ([Id], [Nome]) VALUES (2, N'BBB')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table1] ([Id], [Nome]) VALUES (3, N'CCC')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([Id], [DataVencimento], [Table1_Id]) VALUES (1, CAST(N'2018-01-01' AS Date), 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([Id], [DataVencimento], [Table1_Id]) VALUES (2, CAST(N'2018-01-02' AS Date), 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([Id], [DataVencimento], [Table1_Id]) VALUES (3, CAST(N'2018-01-03' AS Date), 2)
GO
```

Tenho o seguinte relacionamento entre elas:

```
select 
    Table1.Id,
    Table1.Nome,
    Table2.Id,
    Table2.DataVencimento
from Table1 
    inner join Table2 on Table2.Table1_Id = Table1.Id
for xml auto, root('ArrayOfTable1')
```

que produz esse resultado:

```
<ArrayOfTable1>
  <Table1 Id="1" Nome="AAA">
    <Table2 Id="1" DataVencimento="2018-01-01" />
  </Table1>
  <Table1 Id="2" Nome="BBB">
    <Table2 Id="2" DataVencimento="2018-01-02" />
    <Table2 Id="3" DataVencimento="2018-01-03" />
  </Table1>
</ArrayOfTable1>
```

Mas eu preciso que DataVencimento seja um elemento como no xml abaixo:

```
<ArrayOfTable1>
    <Table1 Id="1" Nome="AAA">
        <Table2 Id="1">
            <DataVencimento>2018-01-01</DataVencimento>
        </Table2>
    </Table1>
    <Table1 Id="2" Nome="BBB">
        <Table2 Id="2">
            <DataVencimento>2018-01-02</DataVencimento>
        </Table2>
        <Table2 Id="3">
            <DataVencimento>2018-01-03</DataVencimento>
        </Table2>
    </Table1>
</ArrayOfTable1>
```

Como fazer isso?

Comment: Se você acrescentar ELEMENTS, o resultado é aceitável? Se não, avalie utilizar o modo EXPLICIT.

Comment: Não porque eu preciso de apenas alguns campos como elemento, enquanto ELEMENTS faz tudo ser elemento.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me deram essa solução no stackoverflow em inglês:

```
select 
    Table1.ID,
    Table1.Nome,
    Table2.Id,
    (select table2.DataVencimento for xml path(''), elements, type)
from Table1 
    inner join Table2 on Table2.Table1_Id = Table1.Id
order by Table1.Id, Table2.Id
for xml auto, root('ArrayOfTable1')
```

e que fornece o resultado esperado.

Comment: A abordagem é interessante. E bem mais simples, com o uso de PATH para converter previamente a coluna DataVencimento em elemento.

Answer (score 1):

Eis sugestão que mais se aproxima do que solicita.

```
-- código #1 v3
select 
    1 as Tag,
    0 as Parent,
    T1.Id as [Table1!1!Id],
    T1.Nome as [Table1!1!Nome],
    NULL as [Table2!2!Id],
    NULL as [DataVencimento!3]
  from Table1 as T1 
  where exists(SELECT * from Table2 as T2 where T2.Table1_Id = T1.Id)

union all

select 2, 1, T1.Id, T1.Nome, T2.Id, NULL
  from Table1 as T1 
       inner join Table2 as T2 on T2.Table1_Id = T1.Id

union all

select 3, 2, T1.Id, T1.Nome, T2.id, T2.DataVencimento
  from Table1 as T1 
       inner join Table2 as T2 on T2.Table1_Id = T1.Id

  order by [Table1!1!Id], [Table2!2!Id], [DataVencimento!3] 

  for XML EXPLICIT, ROOT('ArrayOfTable1');
```

Mas é provável que haja forma mais simples de obter o mesmo resultado...

Comment: José obrigado pela resposta! Eu vou usar seu exemplo pra entender o EXPLICIT pq nunca utilizei. Fiz apenas um exemplo simples entre duas tabelas fictícias, mas meu caso real tem relacionamentos entre mais tabelas e mais de uma coluna que preciso retornar como ELEMENT. Eu acho que a query vai ficar complicada e um tanto difícil de ler com essa solução. Vou deixar a pergunta em aberto pra ver se alguém tem uma solução mais simples. Grato